# Access list items inside a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```py
data = {'c1': [[1], [2, 3], [4], [0]],
        'c2': [[0], [0], [12], [5, 6, 7]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: dataframe]

I want to access column values inside the list, specifically with a condition check:

```py
# something like this
df.loc[df['c1'] == 0] # returns empty dataframe
# or
df.loc[df['c1'] == [0]] # returns a ValueError
```

It would be helpful if I can get only the first and last row with the condition check. Thank you!

Comment: Use a list comp `df[[[0]==row for row in df.c1]]`

Comment: It does the work. Thanks!